# Get single column of data from mysql_query result

Tags: php, arrays, merge, numeric, array-column

I am currently using a mysql_query with the UNION function. This is the array that I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bob
    [added] => bob
)
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [added] => test1
)
```

Is there a way that I can take this array, merge it, remove the `added` values, place the data in numerical order and make it look like this?:

```
Array
(
    [0] => bob
    [1] => test1
)
```

I know somebody'll ask me what have I done so far. Honestly, I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Do you have the PHP code where you are iterating over the mysql result object?

Answer (score 2):

```
array_reduce(
    array_map(function($i) {
        return $i[0];
    }, $data),
    function($result, $item) {
        $result[] = $item;
        return $result;
    },
    array()
);
```

or

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge',
    array_map(function($i) {
        return $i[0];
    }, $data)
);
```

Comment: I keep on receiving the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'` for both functions.

Comment: @user2898075: what php version do you use?

Comment: @zerkms I'm currently using 5.2.17

Comment: @user2898075: my code is php 5.3+. So prefer other solutions (just plain old `foreach` would be fine) PS: 5.2.17 is sooooooooooooooooooo old

Comment: @zerkms If you wouldn't mind, can you show me how I could use `foreach` to accomplish what I want? I'm still a noob with arrays.

Comment: @user2898075: at least give it a try first

Answer (score 0):

When you are fetching the data you can create your array eg:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM){
   $newArray[] = $row[0];
 }
```

and from your current array you can do

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    $newArray = array_push($newArray,$value[0]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1=array_unique($array1);
$array2=array_unique($array2);
$result = array_merge ($array1,$array2);
```